# How to update attributes on database using Ruby on Rails 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

I'm working on a controller action and, what I want to do is to modify a record in the data base.

I have the following code:

```
def save_reserve
    @pnr = Pnr.find_by_email(params[:pnr][:email])
    if (!@pnr.blank?)
      @pnr.update_attributes(params[:pnr])
    else
      @pnr = Pnr.new(params[:pnr])
      if @pnr.save
        ...
      else
        ...
      end
    end
  end
```

Why `@pnr.update_attributes(params[:pnr])` doesn't work?

However, if I do:

```
      @pnr.update_attribute(:name, params[:pnr][:name])
      @pnr.update_attribute(:lastname, params[:pnr][:lastname])
      @pnr.update_attribute(:phone, params[:pnr][:phone])
      @pnr.update_attribute(:addr, params[:pnr][:addr])
```

it works... Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`model.update_attributes(hsh)` is effectively the same as calling `model.attributes = hsh; model.save` - it's subject to any callbacks and validations on the object.

`model.update_attribute(field, value)` directly updates that field in the database without any callbacks or validation being run.

If you check the return value of `@pnr.update_attributes(params[:pnr])` you'll probably see it's `false`. You should have an `if [...]` check around this in the same way as you do for your `save` call in the `new` branch of your cose